# Jython and the xml.sax parser - strange error

Tags: python, xml, jython, sax

I am just getting started with Python/Jython and the SAX parser (`xml.sax`). I wrote a simple content handler as a test.

```
from __future__ import with_statement 

from xml.sax import make_parser, handler
from xml.sax.handler import ContentHandler

class CountingHandler(ContentHandler):

    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        self.counter += 1

def main(argv=sys.argv):
    parser = make_parser()
    h = CountingHandler()
    parser.setContentHandler(h)
    with open(argv[1], "r") as input:
        parser.parse(input)
```

When I run this on some documents (not all), I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/sciencenetworks/xmltools.py", line 93, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "src/sciencenetworks/xmltools.py", line 88, in main
    parser.parse(input)
  File "/amd.home/home/staudt/workspace/jython/Lib/xml/sax/drivers2/drv_javasax.py", line 141, in parse
    self._parser.parse(JyInputSourceWrapper(source))
  File "/amd.home/home/staudt/workspace/jython/Lib/xml/sax/drivers2/drv_javasax.py", line 90, in resolveEntity
    return JyInputSourceWrapper(self._resolver.resolveEntity(pubId, sysId))
  File "/amd.home/home/staudt/workspace/jython/Lib/xml/sax/drivers2/drv_javasax.py", line 75, in __init__
    if source.getByteStream():
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'getByteStream'
```

When I look into the source code of `drv_javasax.py`, it seems like input is not recognized as a file like object, which it is.
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's this bug: http://bugs.jython.com/issue1488. Fixed in Jython 2.5.2-b1: http://www.jython.org/latest.html

Comment: I am running Jython 2.5.1 (Release_2_5_1:6813, Sep 26 2009, 13:47:54), I'll try the latest version.

Comment: I guess that was the solution to my problem. Thanks. But now I have a new one: `xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException: <unknown>:1:1: The parser has encountered more than "64,000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the application`

Answer (score 0):

When you insert `print type(input)` after your `with` statement, what do you see?

When you revert to old-style "try/finally" code instead of "with", does it work for all files?

What is different between files that work and files that don't work?

What happens if you change the name `input` to something that doesn't shadow a built-in function?

Comment: a) Input is an open file, I've checked that already. b) Without the with-statement, the error remains. c) I can't say what the difference is. The one with the error contains a reference to a .dtd file, the other one does not. d) I've tried `parser.parse(open("file.xml","r"))`, doesn't change anything.